# Xcode Setting Accessory Mark on Static Cells error

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am having a problem with the Settings page of my app. I have chosen to use static cells so I  have a few table sections with 3-4 cells in each.

In viewDidLoad I load my NSUserDefaults and set the accessory marks like this:

```
...
}
else if ( ... my Condition3 ... ) {
    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
}
UITableViewCell* cell = [settingsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

This works fine and it sets the cell with the matching setting with a Checkmark. However, this is only working for the cells that are on screen by default. Any cells which require scrolling do not contain the checkmark.

Is there a way to fix this, preferably without having to use dynamic cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh, I finally figured it out. cellForRowAtIndexPath crashes the app so I had to do the following:

I set the cells which require a checkmark in my viewDidAppear method using the code above (in the question). I also remove all checkmarks and then add one to the selected cell in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method as I was doing before.

In each of the two methods I set an NSString variable to the .textview.text of the selected cell and then implement this method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myFirstString]] || [cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mySecondString]]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this might help someone.

Comment: It is enough if you set the accessory in the method willDisplayCell. No need to do it in viewDidAppear as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you scroll your cells are rebuilt and the checkmarks are cleaned.

You need to set it up in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```